PairLogit in CatBoost
I have a paired dataset on which I would like to run gradient boosting with pairwise ranking.
My data looks like this:



GROUP_ID
Y
X1
X2




1
1
x_11
x_12


1
0
x_21
x_22


2
1
x_31
x_32


2
0
x_41
x_42



Each entry is either the "winner" (y=1) or the "looser" (y=0) of a pair (GROUP_ID). I have N categorical features X1, ..., XN.
I have been following CatBoost tutorials for CatBoostClassifier and CatBoostRanker and have the following questions:

What is the difference between using CatBoostClassifier with loss_function PairLogit and using CatBoostRanker with loss_function PairLogit?

I ran
 parameters = {
 'iterations': 1000,
 'custom_metric': ['NDCG',...],
 'verbose': False,
 'random_seed': 0,
 'loss_function': 'PairLogit',
 'train_dir': 'PairLogit'}

 model = CatBoostRanker(**parameters)

 model.fit(train_pool, eval_set=test_pool, plot=True)`



My PairLogit training loss converges to 0.61. My PairLogit test loss decreases until a certain number of iterations t and then starts increasing. How should I interpret this?

Then, I ran
model.plot_tree(tree_idx=t-1, pool=validate_pool)

The nodes in the decision tree read {X1} counter_type=Counter prior_numerator=0, value>9. All my features are categorical variables {-1, 0, 1}.
3.a) Why do I see value>a with a>1?
3.b) What does the value in the leaves (val = v) correspond to? I see values between -0.5 and 0.5.
Thank you for your help.
